# export Android resource, so other projects can reference it

Tags: android, android-resources

In Android XML files in any attribute I can reference other resources using syntax @package:type/name. I can access my own package (in which case I can omit package name) or package named "android". What about other packages? Can I somehow export my resources, so other applications can reference them? I don't know why I would like to do that, I'm just curious.

Comment: Hey did you find the solution. If yes please post it here.

Comment: No, I haven't found the solution.